# Delegate event from my activity to screen

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-dialog

I have a activity themed like a dialog and I have it setup so that it finishes when the user click outside. 
    `this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);`

As expected when the user clicks outside, it finishes. The activity is marked as floating activity and is only shown on top of the phone.

Now, if the user click on any other part of screen like the phone button/contact button on home screen, then the activity gets finished, but the user has to click on phone/contact app icon again to open phone/conatct app.

What I want is that if user click outside my activity, then the action must be performed as if the activity is not at all present on screen. Something like notification, which does not prevent user from doing other other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you *might* be able to do this is by using a hidden WindowManager.LayoutParams flag, [FLAG_SLIPPERY](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/WindowManager.java#L1400).

This allows touches starting on your View to continue to whatever View is below when the touch leaves your View but remains on the screen. However, I don't think this will work.

Android prevents you from touching "through" a touchable Window because it assumes that Window should be receiving the TouchEvent. Android also prevents you from programmatically "touching" the screen (without root or system access), most likely for security reasons.

---

I dug through AOSP for a while and found [this](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d08509363c7fc7c68ca5f61d06ca0ddd441e1495/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L3176).

Reading the comments, it's possible to infer that, while what you *see* doesn't take up the whole screen, the Activity's Window does. So, while nothing in your Activity is clicked, the Window is still overlaying everything, just with a transparent background, and is dealing with the touches that aren't passed to your Activity's UI. This brings us back to the "touching through" issue.

Comment: But my activity is only occupying a part of screen. So its not really touch through.I want this behavior for touches outside the screen part where my activity is shown.

Comment: Android is still handling the touch, though, and it won't let anything touch through while your Activity is still displaying, even if it's not where it's currently covering.

Comment: is there any way by which i can create a activity which is not at top of stack? or may activity goes behind as soon as it is created

Comment: Then you can't use your Activity.

Comment: Its fine as long as my activity is present in the stack. I just dont want the user to get disturbed with my activity. Activity can stay at the back of stack and the user can come to it when he wants to.

Comment: @user93796 what are you trying to do with this Activity?

Comment: Showing some content to user. That he can see when if gets time.

Comment: Then there's no point in keeping the Activity open. You'd be much better served (and the user would have a much better experience) to just let Android do its normal lifecycle, killing the Activity when needed. When the Activity is opened, simply display the information.

Comment: I have some usecase for this. Its like a toast, but a persistent one. Which doesnot block users actions.

Comment: But you just said you were fine with it not being displayed to the user. If you want to have a persistent display of something, use the WindowManager and add a non-touchable View.

Comment: Thanks, will try that